# make out of memory

Tags: vps, centos5, memory-usage, mono, make

Using gcc to make mono 2.8 from source on a CentOS 5 VPS with 128mb RAM, and it seems to be hanging. The result of `free-m` shows all memory has been used.

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           128        126          1          0          0          1
-/+ buffers/cache:        124          3
Swap:          127        127          0
```

What can I do to ensure that mono get's built? Will increasing the swap size help this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase swap size and potentially get this done. *Maybe.* It might just go into a spiral of thrashing death.

But the better way is to abandon trying to build large software packages in that much memory. That's a really painfully small amount of RAM for a modern OS. Linux can be memory-light (that's why you can pay for a system like this, after all), but generally it's used that way in a special-purpose, well designed environment.

Running gcc to build mono does not count.

But no reason to give up completely: why not just build the package on a better-endowed CentOS 5 system, and transfer the result over?

Comment: What files would I need to copy across if I ran `make` on a VM here and then put it up on the VPS?

Comment: When you build it, set `PREFIX` to `/opt/mono` or something. Then run `make install`, and after that, copy over the contents. I haven't ever built mono and it might be a bit odd, but that's the basic approach.